# Recently I updated to Android Studio 3.0 .1. Now some layouts are showing cannot render,coordinator layout out overlay

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Recently I updated to Android Studio 3.0 .1. Now some layouts are showing cannot render, cordinator layout out overlay and also showing failed to instantiate one or more classes

**1.gradle module app file**

[image]

**2.cordinator layout overlay**

[image]

**3.XML code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/dd_root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/dd_content_login" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/dd_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/dd_icon_checkmark" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you please upload your XML file also?

Comment: close your tag <include layout="@layout/dd_content_login"/>

Comment: actually, thats, not the problem @YoLo .this code was working before the update and  now i cant just edit the design It is working when i install to the device

Comment: @YoLo it's already closed

Comment: Also  add the included layout

Comment: try to use implementation :  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: thank you @MiteshVanaliya for help

Answer (score 0):

Change target version and update gradle 3.0 also use implementation instead of compile.

Now what is difference between this three *(api,compile,implementation)* keyword

It is one of the changes coming with `gradle:3.0`
is the **compile configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by implementation or api**

- **api:**
  you leak the interface of this module through your own interface, meaning exactly the same as the old compile dependency.
- **implementation:**
  you only use this module internally and does not leak it through your interface.

> Just replace all compile with the implementation and try to build the
>   project.  If it builds successfully, well and good. otherwise look for
>   any leaking dependency you might be using and import those libraries
>   using api keyword.

Hope this may help!